# VS CodeでPythonデバッグモード使用時にlaunch.jsonで設定したコマンドライン引数が読み込めない

Tags: python, vscode

## やりたいこと

`argparse`でコマンドライン引数を受ける仕様のPythonプログラムに対してVS Codeのデバッグモードを使い、`launch.json`で設定した引数をプログラムに渡したい。

## 状況

`argparse`でコマンドライン引数を受ける仕様のPythonファイルに対してVS Codeのデバッグモードを使ったところ、`launch.json`で設定した引数が渡せていないようでエラーが発生しています。

デバッグモードではなく以下のようにコマンドを打ち込んで実行した場合はエラーは出ません。

```
train.py path/to/directory 0 0
```

## コード

**./.vscode/lauch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: train.py",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "train.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "args": [
                "path/to/directory",
                "0",
                "0",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**./train.py**

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyTorch CSRNet')
parser.add_argument('train_path', metavar='TRAIN',
                    help='path to train dataset directory')
parser.add_argument('--pre', '-p', metavar='PRETRAINED', default=None, type=str, 
                    help='path to the pretrained model')
parser.add_argument('gpu', metavar='GPU', type=str, 
                    help='GPU id to use.')
parser.add_argument('task', metavar='TASK', type=str, 
                    help='task id to use.')


def main():
    global args,best_prec1
    best_prec1 = 1e6
    
    args = parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## エラー

### VS Codeのポップアップエラー

`main()` 下の `args = parser.parse_args()` で以下のエラーが出ています。

```
Exception has occurred: SystemExit
2
  File "****/train.py", line 33, in main
    args = parser.parse_args()
  File "****/train.py", line 215, in <module>
    main()
SystemExit: 2
```

### VS Codeのターミナルのエラー

```
usage: train.py [-h] [--pre PRETRAINED] TRAIN GPU TASK
train.py: error: the following arguments are required: TRAIN, GPU, TASK
```

## 環境

Windows 11 WSL (Ubuntu 22.04)
Python 3.10.8 (venv使用)
VS Code version 1.74.3

## その他

不備等ありましたら修正しますので宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+D "実行とデバッグ"で, "Python: train.py"の構成を選択してますか？どのように実行してますか？(Debug:Start Debugging ですか？) / lauch.jsonでの `"program": "train.py"` に指定のミスはありませんか？(別ディレクトリーに同じ名前があるなど) 可能なら `"program": "${file}",` と記述し `train.py`開いておいて開始すると間違いないかも

Comment: argsの記述ですが、"train_path=path/to/directory"というように記述したら動作しないでしょうか？'='の前後にスペース不要です。また、VScodeでF5デバッグ実行すると、ターミナルに、フルパスの実行コマンドライン記述が表示されて、末尾に指定したargsオプションがシングルコーテーションで囲まれて表示されると思います。その記述通りに、手動でスクリプトに引数を渡して実行できるでしょうか？

Comment: @oriri  さん　Ctrl+Shift+D "実行とデバッグ"をせずに直接VS Codeウィンドウ右上のデバッグボタンを押して実行していましたが、Ctrl+Shift+D "実行とデバッグ"、"Python: train.py"の構成を選択で実行することでコマンドライン引数をちゃんと渡せました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: @TakahiroFunahashi  ご指摘のようにVScodeでF5デバッグ実行でちゃんとコマンドライン引数を渡せました。VS Code画面右上のデバッグボタンから実行していたため、`launch.json`の設定が通っていなかったようです。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(コメントから回答へ)

VS Codeのデバッガー機能については以下のページ

- [Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

その中の, Python でのデバッガー機能は以下のページがあります

- [Python debugging in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)

それによると以下のような項目が記されています

- "configuration" で指定する。それは `launch.json` ファイル内に定義されている。ファイルが存在しなければ尋ねられ作成される
- **Run and Debug** view (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) でデバッガーのドロップダウンリストから適切な "configuration" を選択しデバッガーを開始する

"configuration" では対象のプログラムを以下のように指定。(`${file}` は現在開いているファイル名)

```
    "program": "${file}",
```

このことから, 上記に挙げた項目のどこかに間違った指定があると思われます
(今回の場合は, 適切な "configuration" が選択されていなかった)

※ あと, 細かいことながら, JSONでの記述は配列などの項目の最後には `,` は付かないことになっていて, VS Codeではうまいこと解釈してくれるけど下手な JSONパーサーだと認識できないかも
(`args` の最後)